# How to select a date from bootstrap calendar which is read only in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the calendar which we are using in the application, this field is read only i have to select the date automatically, i cant be able to inspect the calendar as the code is disappearing automatically when we click on the calendar because of that i cant be able to write code in selenium

[image]

Comment: can u share credentials

Comment: just try with `sendKeys`

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

DatePicker are not Select element.

Datepicker are in fact table with set of rows and columns.To select a date you just have to navigate to the cell where our desired date is present.

So your code should be like this:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(your locator);
List<WebElement> columns=we.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

for (WebElement cell: columns){
   //Select 13th Date 
   if (cell.getText().equals("13")){
      cell.findElement(By.linkText("13")).click();
      break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,and let me know if it has worked for you

```
 WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your locator"));
    List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    for (WebElement cell: columns){
       //Select 13th Date 
       if (cell.getText().equals("13")){
          cell.findElement(By.linkText("13")).click();
          break;
     }
```